# Howto integrate static code analysis (SonarCube) into ship.io for mobile projects?

Tags: android, ios, continuous-integration, sonarqube

We have a setup where we want to use https://ship.io/ as our cloud-based continuous-integration server.

However we also want to have some kind of static code analysis (preferably SonarCube but that is debatable), which isn't supported officially by ship.io.
The Projects are classic mobile Projects (Android and iOS).

I have seen some posts of people mentioning that they managed to setup this kind of configuration. SonarCube just has released a gradle plugin http://www.sonarsource.com/2015/06/15/sonarqube-gradle-1-0-released/ so the Android part should be doable.

However at the moment i have no idea what would be the best way do do this for the iOS part of the project.

We already contacted the ship.io team on this issue but did not recieve a response yet.

Any suggestions/insights on this?

Answer (score 4):

My name is Tim Rosenblatt and I'm one of the senior engineers here at Ship.io. I'm not sure why you didn't get a reply from our support email, and I'm glad you posted about this here.

As Viktor mentioned, we definitely support custom scripts. You absolutely can run whatever you like during your build process with this type of step.

I've got a few links that should be helpful for you in getting SonarCube added to your Ship job, but you can definitely get in touch with us if anything isn't clear enough for you. You can use the in-app support icon at the bottom right of your dashboard, or just email me personally -- tim at ship dot io

http://support.ship.io/environment/install-software

http://support.ship.io/environment/custom-shell-scripts

Thanks!

Comment: did anybody already do this? Having an example would save lots of time.
installing sonar should be as easy as "brew install sonar", but i think there must also be a running and configured DB on the server.

Comment: also i am a bit concerned about the impact on the server. Do we really have to run the setup on every build?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to write a script (bash, ruby, ...) which runs your static code analysis and then call that script on your own Mac or on any CI which supports running custom scripts. AFAIK ship.io does support this, our service (https://bitrise.io/ - CTO here) certainly does.

Comment: Hi Viktor, can you please develop this answer? I'm setting up a remote sonarqube server and want to analyse the code each time a push is done in my iOS/Android repository. What are the steps we need to follow in the bitrise workflow? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use a Script step and run the commands you'd run on your Mac/Linux (http://devcenter.bitrise.io/tips-and-tricks/install-additional-tools/)